# Crash assertion failure in -[firtrace inittracewithname:], firtrace.m:86. NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Name cannot be nil FCMSDK update

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

[qgL7c.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZA6z.png)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQFtK.jpg

After updating latest FCM SDK I am getting my app crash.
trace = Performance.startTrace(name: url.absoluteString)

error log
Crash assertion failure in -[firtrace inittracewithname:], firtrace.m:86. NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Name cannot be nil FCMSDK update

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include code and structures as text so we can use them in answers with copy/paste. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Images and links are not searchable so they may not be of use to future readers, and if the link breaks, it would invalidate the question. Also, please indicate what troubleshooting you've done by stepping through you code to determine which line is crashing. Lastly, please ensure your cocoapods is up-to-date (if using cocoapods) and ensure you have the current version of Firebase installed.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful if the string passed to `Performance.startTrace(name:)` is longer than 100 characters. Internally they are performing some sanitization with the string in a static method called `NSString *FPRReservableName(NSString *name)` which is not an honest API as you can see:

```
NSString *FPRReservableName(NSString *name) {
  NSString *reservableName =
      [name stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
  if ([reservableName hasPrefix:kFPRInternalNamePrefix]) {
    FPRLogError(kFPRClientNameReserved, @"%@ prefix is reserved. Dropped %@.",
                kFPRInternalNamePrefix, reservableName);
    return nil;
  }

  if (reservableName.length == 0) {
    FPRLogError(kFPRClientNameLengthCheckFailed, @"Given name is empty.");
    return nil;
  }

  if (reservableName.length > kFPRMaxNameLength) {
    FPRLogError(kFPRClientNameLengthCheckFailed, @"%@ is greater than %d characters, dropping it.",
                reservableName, kFPRMaxNameLength);
    return nil;
  }

  return reservableName;
}
```

Of course this is totally unnacceptable because it leads to unexpected crashes at runtime.